# How to plot ggplot2 polar with discret/continuous values instead of counting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

with the code below

```
dft <- data.frame(f1=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D'), 
                  f2=c("F1", "F1", "F2", 'F2', 'F3', 'F1'))
d <- ggplot(dft, aes(x =f1, fill=f2))
d <- d + geom_bar(width = 1, position = "fill")
d + coord_polar("x")
```

I get this chart

[image]

The number of sectors is determined by f1, and the records counts produce the proportion of f2 on each f1 accordingly.

But I want to have the sectors filled based on a continuous/discrete aggregated value.

Instead of

```
dft <- data.frame(f1=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D'), 
                  f2=c("F1", "F1", "F2", 'F2', 'F3', 'F1'))
```

I'd have

```
dft2 <- data.frame(f1=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
                   f2=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3"), 
                   value=c(5,10,15, 2,30,30, 10, 10,20))
```

is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean with "the sectors filled based on a continuous/discrete aggregated value."?

Comment: @GGamba in the example from dft2 data sector A would have its are filled (coloured) in proportion to 5, 10, 15, sector B to 2, 30, 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dft2 <- data.frame(f1=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
                   f2=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3"), 
                   value=c(5,10,15, 2,30,30, 10, 10,20))

d2 <- ggplot(dft2, aes(x = f1, y = f2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'dodgerblue1', high = 'dodgerblue4') +
  coord_polar("x") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

It uses `geom_col` and the `y` aesthetic, mapping it to `f2`, while `fill`ing by the `value` dimension.
Colors are just for fun. Change or remove as you wish.

[image]

If you want each `f2` area relative to its `value` change the `y` aesthetic to `value`:

```
d2 <- ggplot(dft2, aes(x = f1, y = value, fill = value)) + 
  geom_col(width = 1, position = 'fill', color = 'black', size = .5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'dodgerblue1', high = 'dodgerblue4') +
  coord_polar("x") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I'm saving here for further reference, but having sector B as an example, what I'm looking for is to fill that area with 3 colors,  2/62 of the circular area in one color for F1, 30/62 of the sector area for F2 and F3.

Comment: added relative area

Comment: Excellent!  I used f2 as fill and it works!  :)  One final question.  Do you know how do I control the size (thickness) and color fo the sector contours?  Here I don't get the same black thick lines as borders for the sectors.

Comment: I'm sorry, something went wrong copy-pasting. The 'black line' dividing the sectors is achieved using `color = 'black'` inside `geom_col`. And you can control its thickness with `size = ..`, again inside `geom_col`. Editing to make it explicit